# I wanted to create a user profile in sharepoint using powershell scripting

Tags: powershell

I have used the below code for fetching the user profile from sharepoint 2010.Error I am getting is object $cm is returning as null.

$site = Get-SPSite($PortalURL);
$servercontext = [Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext]::GetContext($site);
$site.Dispose();

## Return the UserProfileConfigManager

$cm = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileConfigmanager($servercontext);
$spm = Get-SPProfileManager $siteUrl

Please help me to resolve this.I have checked the user profile service and its up and ruuning.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are disposing the connection before you should.  Dispose at the end and you should be good